# How to create home page cms template from local.xml in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am creating a magento theme. I set 2columns-right layout for all page. Now I want to create a template and set 1columns layout for home page from local.xml. But admin home page cms selected layout still remains and my created and admin home page cms content both still show. So how can I avoid admin home page cms layout and content without disable and set 1columns layout for home page.  Any suggestion and help are appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <!-- Global Operations -->
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="some_random_name" template="cms/home.phtml"/>
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action> -->
            <!-- <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action> -->
            <!-- <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> -->
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```